# Firefox addon sdk packaging

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I packaged my addon and tested in firefox 31 , it worked fine.

I try to install it on firefox 21 , I got an error mentioning invalid package addon/sdk/window

my question is how could i include packages so that it could work on firefox 21?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to support Firefox 21? Firefox 21 is not supported anymore by mozilla, at all. **It has known security vulnerabilities!** My advice would be to not even try to support Firefox 21 at all. Do not encourage users to use a known insecure browser version.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that will be supported, as firefox is improving day by day, and changes in the version of SDKs also.
Also, the firefox v21, must not be supporting the SDK packed addons. You should create them using XUL.

Answer (score 0):

cfx has the option `--force-use-bundled-sdk` to bundle the sdk libraries themselves with the XPI, but that doesn't guarantee that those modules will work in older firefox versions

You could also wrap the module `require()` in try-catch blocks and use older APIs on failure. I think some modules were renamed over time

Also, FF21 is long out of support. At the time of writing 31.4.0esr is the oldest still maintained release.